SDL window displaying only when running the binary directly and not with cargo run
I was trying to make a simple program that opens a SDL window that I can use for a game, and used the demo code from the rust-SDL github shown below.
main.rs
extern crate sdl2;

use sdl2::event::Event;
use sdl2::keyboard::Keycode;
use sdl2::pixels::Color;
use std::time::Duration;

pub fn main() -> Result<(), String> {
    let sdl_context = sdl2::init()?;
    let video_subsystem = sdl_context.video()?;

    let window = video_subsystem
        .window("rust-sdl2 demo: Video", 800, 600)
        .position_centered()
        .opengl()
        .build()
        .map_err(|e| e.to_string())?;

    let mut canvas = window.into_canvas().build().map_err(|e| e.to_string())?;

    canvas.set_draw_color(Color::RGB(255, 0, 0));
    canvas.clear();
    canvas.present();
    let mut event_pump = sdl_context.event_pump()?;

    let mut count = 0;

    'running: loop {
        println!("running frame {}", count);
        count += 1;
        for event in event_pump.poll_iter() {
            match event {
                Event::Quit { .. }
                | Event::KeyDown {
                    keycode: Some(Keycode::Escape),
                    ..
                } => break 'running,
                _ => {}
            }
        }

        canvas.clear();
        canvas.present();
        ::std::thread::sleep(Duration::new(0, 1_000_000_000u32 / 30));
    }

    Ok(())
}

Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "test_window"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
gl = "*"
sdl2 = { version = "*", features = ["bundled"] }

The problem is that when running cargo run, the code build and starts to execute but no window is displayed. The println! in the loop is running and showing the expected frames (30 per second but no window is shown).
running program with cargo build, no window
but running the program either from the terminal with target/debug/test_window or by simply double clicking it from the file manager shows the window which looks like this:
running the program directly with terminal or file manager
The results are the same for both the terminal in nvim and the normal terminal. I Know it is very easy to get around this problem but I want to fix it now before it could turn into a larger and harder to debug problem in the future. I am on Debian 12, installed rust-up today for cargo. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Just encountered this myself. Did you ever get a solution figured out?
